# Why doesn't my config change when clicking a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to make my checkbox change a variable to true when it's checked, but everytime I click on it, it just refreshes the page and leaves the config value as false.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="music">
```

JQuery Code:

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var music = document.getElementsByName("music")
            $(music).click(function() {
                window.location.href = 'validate.php?music';
            })
        });
</script>
```

Code from validate.php:

```
if (isset($_POST["music"])) {
    $config -> SetVar("music_status", "true", "Music Status");
} else {
    $config -> SetVar("music_status", "false", "Music Status");
}
```

The SetVar function does work as I use it for other things, it just doesn't want to seem to work with my checkbox. Any help and tips would be appreciated in helping me fix this.

Comment: Use _GET instead of _POST since your code uses a redirect and not form submit with action=post.

Comment: That allowed me to change the value to true, but now it stays true and won't change to false.

Comment: window.location.href = (window.location.href.indexOf('music') !=-1) ?  'validate.php' : 'validate.php?music';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're always setting the $_GET['music'] but you're not setting it to anything nor are you checking its value.
change your javascript to

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var music = document.getElementsByName("music")[0].checked;
        $(music).click(function() {
            window.location.href = 'validate.php?music=' + music;
        })
    });
```

And your php code to

```
if (isset($_GET["music"]) && $_GET['music'] == 'true') {
```

Comment: I had to change some things, but for the most part this helped. Thanks!